# Describe the level surfaces of the following function: $f(x, y, z) = x^2 − y^2 + z^2$

Tags: geometry, surfaces, quadrics

**Question:** Describe the level surfaces of the following function: $f(x, y, z) = x^2 − y^2 + z^2$

I'm currently trying find the surface in which the function represents but I can't seem to figure out. I'm leaning into thinking it's a elliptic cone with its format as there's two positives. Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost the canonical equation of a [hyperboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid), so this is what the surface will be. Some intuition on the three types of hyperboloid is provided below. The TL; DR is that you can rotate a hyperbola either about its major axis or about its conjugate axis (the axis between the two sheets), giving rise to two different kinds of hyperboloid.

The level curves verify
$$x^2-y^2+z^2=A$$
for some $A$, or equivalently
$$y^2-r^2=-A$$
where $r^2=x^2+z^2$. This means that $y$ depends on $x$ and $z$ only through $r$, which is the distance from the point $(x, y, z)$ to the $Y$ axis. Therefore, the surface is **rotationally symmetric about the $Y$ axis**.

There are three cases depending on the sign of $A$. Nice plots of the three possibilities have been provided by Raffaele in their [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3973831/495620).

- If $A$ is positive, let $A=a^2$, and we have
  $$\frac{r^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{a^2}=1$$
  which is the equation of a [hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Equation) with asymptotes $r=\pm y$ and vertices at $(r=\pm a, y=0)$. The surface is this hyperbola rotated about the $Y$ axis.
- If $A$ is $0$, then we have the degenerate case $y^2= r^2$, or $y=\pm r$, which is a cone along the $Y$ axis.
- If $A$ is negative, let $A=-a^2$, and we have
  $$\frac{y^2}{a^2}-\frac{r^2}{a^2}=1$$
  which is the equation of a hyperbola with asymptotes $r=\pm y$ and vertices at $(r=0, y=\pm a)$. This is the same hyperbola as in the positive $A$ case, but with the $Y$ and $R$ axes swapped. The surface is this hyperbola rotated about the $Y$ axis.

Answer (score 2):

There are three level surfaces. The other ones are very similar. If you need a level surface for a specific value, feel free to ask.

The first one is the equation of a cone with symmetry axis the $y$-axis

The second and the third ones are a hyperbolic hyperboloid
$$\Large x^2-y^2+z^2=0$$
[image]
$$\Large x^2-y^2+z^2=1$$
[image]
$$\Large x^2-y^2+z^2=-1$$
[image]

Comment: Thanks Raffaele! That's why I was having trouble to find the solution. Would it be possible for you to elaborate on why there are three level surfaces so that I understand the reasoning behind?